# evalute limite with quotient and roots

Tags: limits, roots

can someone please evaluate this limit for me I have been trying for hours.

the original limit was : 
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt[4]{x+1}-\sqrt[4]{x}}{\sqrt[3]{x+1}-\sqrt[3]{x}}\times{\sqrt[12]{x}}$$

but after some adjustment that I made the limit becomes :
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt[4]{1+\frac{1}{x}}-1}{\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{1}{x}}-1}\times{\frac{\sqrt[4]{x}}{\sqrt[3]{x}}}  \times{\sqrt[12]{x}}$$
  then  $(t=1+\frac{1}{x})$ :

$$\lim_{t\to 1} \frac{\sqrt[4]{t}-1}{\sqrt[3]{t}-1}$$

now I don't know what is the next step

Comment: use the formula $$\lim_{x \to a}\frac{x^{n} - a^{n}}{x - a} = na^{n - 1}$$ and write $$\lim_{t \to 1}\frac{\sqrt[4]{t} - 1}{\sqrt[3]{t} - 1} = \lim_{t \to 1}\dfrac{\dfrac{t^{1/4} - 1}{t - 1}}{\dfrac{t^{1/3} - 1}{t - 1}} = \frac{1/4}{1/3} = \frac{3}{4}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v=\sqrt[12]{t}$.  Then your limit is $$\lim_{v\rightarrow 1} \frac{v^3-1}{v^4-1}.$$

Then you can factor out a $v-1$ to get $$\lim_{v\rightarrow 1} \frac{v^2+v+1}{v^3+v^2+v+1} = \frac{3}{4}.$$

Comment: brilliant solution  you saved me thanks man